# Is there a way to do this in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

Consider I have a `Task` class like this :

```
class Task {
     String title
     Date   assignedOn
     User user
}
```

Now the `user` can have many `tasks`. Now consider there are 8 `tasks` already assigned to `userX`. Now the `manager`(a special kind of `user`) is creating a 2 tasks to that `userX`, now I have totally `10` tasks of the `userX`. It is easy to display all the 10 `tasks` to that user.

But what I want is, I need a way to display only those 2 `tasks` to that `userX` assuming that the `userX` have already viewed those 8 `tasks`.

A real world example would be Stackoverflow site itself. If the person is answering my question I get a notification stating `1 new answer on the q.....` and I will view it. After some time, if any one answers my same question, I get a notification stating `1 new answer` not `2 new answer` as I have already viewed the first answer.

What are the ways I can use to do this? Any plugins available for this in grails?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, i would add a boolean flag on the Task class to indicate if it has been viewed or not by the user like so:

```
class Task {
  String title
  Date dateAssigned
  boolean viewStatus  // true indicates a read task

  static belongsTo = [assignedTo: User, assignedBy: User]
}
```

When creating a task the `viewStatus` flag would be set to false. Whenever the user views a particular task the `viewStatus` flag would be set by your program to true. It is therefore possible to query for just the un-read tasks to display to your user (using GORM) like so:

```
def currentUser = // your currently logged in user
Task.findTaskByViewStatusAndAssignedTo(false, currentUser)
```

The query will return only any user tasks that have not been read by the user, assuming that the readStatus is properly set whenever a user reads a task.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with a plugin, but your design of the `Task` class. Without knowing more about your requirements, you could do something like this:

```
class Task {
    String title
    Date assignedOn
    User user
    Boolean isAssignedByManager
}
```

I added `User user` because you need to be able to tell who the task was assigned to (don't know how your are doing this at the moment). Then just set `isAssignedByManager` to `true` when the manager is assigning the task so you can search by it later:

```
Task.findByUserAndIsAssignedByManager(userInstance, true)
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't show up the whole class file. I missed out that `User user` line.

Comment: Well, the `tasks` can be only assigned by the `manager`. So there is no point in using that `Boolean isAssignedByManager` line.

Comment: how do you know that the user has seen the 8 tasks? maybe you need a `Boolean isSeen` and set it to true when the user sees it. then you can identify the 2 new tasks by searching `Task.findByIsSeen(false)`